# Why request for permission in CloudKit returns CouldNotComplete?

Tags: cloudkit

I try to fetch user record from cloud kit container. I request permission for it, but now, at this time I get a `CouldNotComplete` return value. Why, problem is on my side?

```
defaultContainer.requestApplicationPermission(.PermissionUserDiscoverability, {status, error in

    if status == CKApplicationPermissionStatus.Granted {

    } else if status == CKApplicationPermissionStatus.CouldNotComplete {
        println(error.userInfo)
    }
```

This is the exact error message:

> [NSErrorFailingURLStringKey:
>   https://configuration.apple.com/configurations/internetservices/cloudkit/cloudkit-1.0.plist,
>   _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey: 57, NSErrorFailingURLKey: https://configuration.apple.com/configurations/internetservices/cloudkit/cloudkit-1.0.plist,
>   _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey: 1, NSDebugDescription: NSURLErrorDomain: -1005, NSUnderlyingError: Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1005 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (NSURLErrorDomain error -1005.)"
>   UserInfo=0x7b96fb30
>   {NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://configuration.apple.com/configurations/internetservices/cloudkit/cloudkit-1.0.plist,
>   _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=57, NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://configuration.apple.com/configurations/internetservices/cloudkit/cloudkit-1.0.plist,
>   _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=1}]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In somehow I forget to log in my iCloud account in simulator, that is why I get this error.